# OpenSearch - facets from outside the current result set

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

Suppose I have an online clothing store, and I'm using OpenSearch to let the users filter the products. Each product has the following fields, the field type is `keyword`:

- type (shirt, pants, jacket)
- color (red, blue, pink)
- size (XL, L, M, S)

I want to add facets to the search UI. I'm using [terms aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to implement that, and it's working well, up to a point. If no filters are being applied, I can get facets for all of the fields, so I can show the users that there are 50 red items, 45 blue, 66 pink, and so on for all the other fields. My dilemma is how to get facets from *outside* the current result set. For example, if the user selects blue for the color, then all the items in the results will be blue, so I can't get facet values for pink or red. I want to show how many results there would be if the color filter was changed. And I want to be able to do this for all the fields, even if more than one filter is selected.

I could send a separate query to get those facets: if the main query contains a color filter, then make a copy of the query, remove the color filter, and add an aggregation for color. But I imagine this wouldn't scale very well if I want to do it for multiple fields (in reality, I have a lot more than 3 fields, the above is just for illustration). Is there a way to accomplish what I want using just a single query?

Would I be better off using the `facets` API instead of aggregations?